# Error- SpeechSynthesisUtterance stops in between for Italian language

Tags: google-chrome, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

**Environment Information :**

- *OS- Windows 10 Pro*
- *Browser - Chrome Version 74.0.3729.169*

On trying to have this particular text:

`Alice stava cominciando ad essere molto stanca di sedersi accanto alla sorella sulla riva e di non avere niente da fare una o due volte che aveva sbirciato nel libro che sua sorella stava leggendo ma non aveva immagini o conversazioni al suo interno`

to speak using SpeechSynthesisUtterance, the speech stops abruptly at the last word `interno`. it just pronounces `int` and the rest of the text gets ignored.

This happens to any other word, just the first two-three words  characers out of the last word get spoken.

It's not because of the character limit of utterance as it is much less than the defined limit i.e. 500 chars.

English, on the other hand, works all right but facing issues similarly for languages like Hindi.

It is to note that:

- *This issue occurs only on Chrome*
- *Italian and Hindi are both **browser-native** languages in Chrome for the Speech Synthesis API*
- *The **OnEnd** callback also does not fire when the same happens.*